# Possible reasons for read/write-errors on ext4 partitions (not SSD)?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, ntfs, ext4

Imagine the following setup:

- Copying a backup from one HDD to another HDD, both connected to PC via USB 3
- Source-HDD: 2 TB, `NTFS`-formatted
- Target-HDD: 3 TB, `EXT4`-formatted
- Executing OS: Debian Stretch, booted via live-cd

---

When copying files via file browser with an overall size of 1 TB from the source HDD to the target HDD the copy progress failed two times reporting the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdd1 at /run/media/root/Backup-Disk:
Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdd1" "/run/media/root/Backup-Disk"´
exited with non-zero exit status 32:
mount /dev/sdd1: can't read superblock
```

Afterwards I could neither mount nor unmount the target drive and had to repair or reformat it before starting a new copy attempt.

---

However, when using a different target disk the whole progress worked without any problems. The executing operating system was Debian Stretch and both the source disk as well as target disks are not SSD-drives.

The failures occurred each at different positions of the copy progress: The first time it happened at around 60 % completion, second time at around 95 % completion. In both cases I could fix the filesystem using `e2fsck` and continue the copy progress. However, this should not occur I think?

---

1. What could be the reason for such a failure with only one disk?
2. Should I better replace the disk to be safe?

Comment: Have you checked the S.M.A.R.T values of your drives? May be one drive is close to defect and you can see that in the SMART values.

Comment: I will check if the failure appears next time! Thank you!